# Laravel application on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, routing only works when index.php is put in the URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-routing

I am deploying my Laravel application to the AWS ElasticBeanstalk. I have deployed it. This is how I deployed it. I created an environment. Then I set the Document Root as '/public'. Then I deployed my application by running "be deploy" command. The application has been deployed successfully. But there is an issue with my application. If I want to access the route for example, I have to access something like this.

http://myan-eat-test.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/index.php/contact-us

as you can see, I have to put in index.php. If I do this, http://myan-eat-test.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/contact-us, it does not work.

I tried created a .htaccess file with the following content in the root folder either.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably should add if you're using Apache. If you're using Nginx, this will not work. I can't offer any help, as I haven't figured it out yet myself for my yii2 project on Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Default proxy server is `nginx` in elastic beanstalk to use apache which is the only server keeping your .htaccess in mind you need to add a `.ebextensions/apache.config` file with:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:
    ProxyServer: apache
```

See also:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-specific.html#command-options-docker